How to reconnect to a URL with python selenium
I've a Selenium-Python test suite which is used to run regression tests for an UI application.
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup(request):
  driver = None
  try:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.get(TestData_common.BASE_URL)
except WebDriverException as e:
    print('UAT seems to be down...> ', e)
yield driver
if driver is not None:
    print("Quitting the driver..")
    driver.quit()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
@pytest.mark.incremental
class Test_InvPayment:

  def test_001_login(self):
    """Login to UAT and click AGREE button in Site Minder"""
    assert TestData_common.URL_FOUND, "UAT seems to be down.."
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_click_agree_button()
    assert TestData_common.AGREE_BTN_FOUND, "Unable to click Site Minder AGREE btn"
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    print('Successfully clicked AGREE button in SiteMinder')
    time.sleep(2)

def test_002_enter_user_and_password(self):
    """Enter User name for UAT"""
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    TestData_common.UserEnabled = True
    self.loginPage.do_enter_user_name(TestData_common.USER_NAME_6, 'USER')
    assert TestData_common.UserEnabled, "Unable to enter User Name.."
    print('Entered User name:', TestData_common.USER_NAME_6)
    time.sleep(2)

def test_003_enter_password(self):
    """Enter Password for Treasury"""
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_enter_password(TestData_common.PASSWORD, 'PASS')
    assert TestData_common.PasswordEnabled, "Unable to enter Password.."
    print('Entered password:', TestData_common.PASSWORD)
    time.sleep(2)

def test_004_click_login_button(self):
    """Click LOGIN button"""
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_click_login_button()
    assert TestData_common.LOGIN_BTN_FOUND, "Unable to click LOGIN button.."
    print('Clicked LOGIN button')

This code works well on most times.
Sometimes the siteminder application which sits in front of the UAT application which is responsible for re-directing the traffic to the UAT application.This is where I enter the user/pwd and login to the app. Sometimes for whatever reason the siteminder application doesn't re-direct to the UAT app and in those cases all the tests following test_004 fails.
In those cases, I want to build a re-try mechanism to again launch the URL and try logging in one more time. Is there a way to do this here? All I want is after clicking the login button from test_004, if the UAT application is not launched, the control goes back to the login page.
Any help is much appreciated.

Some feedback...

What you currently have labeled as tests are actually steps of a test. A test should complete all steps and validate something. Each test should open a browser, do some steps, assert one or more things, and quit the browser. That way each test is self-contained, it does not rely on other "tests" to set state, etc. and it uses it's own browser instance so different tests don't pollute each other. This also allows you to run each test in parallel gaining a huge speed increase in suite runtime.

From what you are describing, I'm assuming you aren't actually testing the Site Minder application... you just have to pass through it to get to the application you want to test. If this is true, logging into and validating that it passed you to the UAT URL should be part of setup().

When catching an exception, catch only exceptions you plan to handle and only specific exceptions. Catching WebDriverException and then claiming that UAT is down seems misdirected.

A lot of the asserts you have are not needed. For example, you are asserting that you found the Agree button *after* you already clicked it. If it wasn't there, an exception would have already been thrown.

driver.maximize_window() should be in setup() right after the driver is created.

Everything doesn't have to be attached to self, e.g. loginPage. You can create an instance of the page, use it, and dispose of it after the test is complete.


Given this feedback, I would rewrite your code to something like this.
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup(request):
    driver = None
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    log_into_siteminder()
    yield driver
    if driver is not None:
        print("Quitting the driver..")
        driver.quit()

def log_into_siteminder(self):
    """Attempts to log into SiteMinder and get into UAT up to three times"""
    max_attempts = 3
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < max_attempts:
        self.driver.get(TestData_common.BASE_URL)
        loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        loginPage.do_click_agree_button()
        TestData_common.UserEnabled = True # I don't know what this does
        loginPage.do_enter_user_name(TestData_common.USER_NAME_6, 'USER')
        loginPage.do_enter_password(TestData_common.PASSWORD, 'PASS')
        loginPage.do_click_login_button()
        if driver.current_url == UAT_URL:
            break
        else:
            attempts += 1
    raise Exception(f"UAT could not be reached after {max_attempts} attempts.")

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class Test_InvPayment:
    def test_001_create_payment(self):
        """Create a payment"""
        # Steps:
        # 1. Login to UAT [already done in setup()]
        # 2. Select a client [is this the UAT client you referred to or something else?]
        # 3. Go to payments page
        # 4. Fill all the fields in that page
        # 5. Check for validation errors etc
        # 6. Save the payment

NOTE: I don't have all of your code so I couldn't test the above code so I may have made typos that weren't caught, etc. but it should point you in the right direction for cleaning up your tests and how to handle passing through SiteMinder cleanly.
So each test execution looks like this:

setup() is called which starts the browser and handles logging into SiteMinder from log_into_siteminder().
The test starts, e.g. test_001_create_payment(), which runs through the scenario and does validation.
Finally, teardown() is called to quit the browser and take care of any other steps required at the end of each test, e.g. logging, etc.

You can create many tests that walk through this process... setup(), test, teardown(). Each test would have it's own browser, etc. Now with this setup, you can start running the suite in parallel. So if you had 10 tests, your current process would run test 1, test 2, test 3, ..., test 10... one right after the other. With parallel execution, all 10 tests could run at the same time so in the time it takes to run the longest test, all tests would be completed. It's a huge time savings if you have a lot of tests.

Thank you for your feedback. This is an application which is supposed to be tested as a workflow, rather than individual pieces. For instance one of the functionality of the app is to create payments. For this the steps are login to UAT, select a client, go to payments page, fill all the fields in that page, check for validation errors etc and finally save the payment. So all these have to happen one after the other. So from your first point, each step can't open a browser and quit after doing something. That's the reason I've broken tests into manageable pieces and test them at one go.

I didn't say each step should open a browser, I said each TEST should open a browser. Your flow is a perfect example. That entire flow is a single test. You should open a browser, login to UAT, select a client, go to payments page, fill all the fields in that page, check for validation errors etc, save the payment, and quit the browser.

log_into_siteminder() is called inside setup() already.

Thank you. "Each TEST should open a browser" - can you show me an example of this from the above code? I might have understood that..

I removed the sample tests that I created before and added test_001_create_payment() as an example test that you were requesting. You would still need to implement a teardown() method that quits the browser and handles anything else that you need to do at the end of each script.

I just added some more explanation at the end of my answer walking through how each test runs, etc.
